# PHP/MySQL: Declare variables using array elements from MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve data from my database and assign the array elements to PHP variables that I wish to use throughout my program so that I don't have to worry about posting separate form data later on.

I know the query I currently have set up is currently working from previous tests but when I try to use a FOR loop to output variables I've assigned from the MySQL query result, only the first element from the database is displayed.

PHP/MySQL Code:

```
// Retrieve tasks from the tasks table 
$tasks_sql = "SELECT DISTINCT taskname FROM tasks";
$tasks_result = mysqli_query($usermysqli, $tasks_sql);
if (! $tasks_result){
      die('Could not retrieve data: ' . mysql.error());
    }

// Array for assigning tasknames to global variables

while($tasks_displayed = $tasks_result->fetch_array()) {

for ($i=0, $inputlen = count($tasks_displayed); $i < $inputlen; $i++) {
${'line'.($i+1)} = $tasks_displayed[$i];
}

}   

// Test to see if the array above actually worked.
echo "Task 1 from array: " . $line1 . "<br>";
echo "Task 2 from array: " . $line2 . "<br>";
echo "Task 3 from array: " . $line3 . "<br>";
echo "Task 4 from array: " . $line4 . "<br>";
echo "Task 5 from array: " . $line5 . "<br>";
echo "Task 6 from array: " . $line6 . "<br>";
```

Only the first element is displayed properly and variables $line2 - $line6 are currently null.  Is this a simple coding error?

Comment: You seem to be mixing OOP and procedural.  Not sure if that's the problem, but if you're using `mysqli_query`, you probably don't want `$tasks_result->fetch_array()` (instead something like `mysqli_fetch_array($tasks_result)`.

Comment: Just tried using "mysqli_fetch_array($tasks_result)" in my "while" statement but now none of the returned results from the query are displayed.  In other words, $line1 is now null

Comment: Your `for` loop is also odd.  Try correcting its syntax to something like `for($i = 0; $i < $inputlen; $i++)` (and defining `$inputlen` before the loop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `for` loop is nested inside your `while` fetch loop *and* you are using the `for` loop to populate individual variables, on **each loop iteration** you are overwriting the same variable. In other words, on every fetch, you get back an array of 1 row having 1 element. The `for` loop then goes over that single row and populates only the first variable, again and again.

The `for` loop needs to happen *after* the `while` loop, once all rows have been fetched into an array.

```
// Fetch an associative array
// array to hold all tasks
$tasks = array();
// Also, consider sticking with the procedural method since that's what you use elsewhere
while ($tasks_displayed = $tasks_result->fetch_assoc()) {
// procedural alternate:
// while ($tasks_displayed = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tasks_result)) {
  // Append the task onto your array
  $tasks[] = $tasks_displayed['taskname'];
}
// Following the loop you now have an array of tasks.
// you can use a for loop to display them:
$tasklength = count($tasks);
for ($i = 0; $i < $tasks; $i++) {
  // Populate your variables...
  ${'line'.($i+1)} = $tasks[$i];
}
```

#### But...

That said, an incrementing `for` loop is really uncommonly used in PHP. `foreach` is almost always p preferred.  If you really must populate these local variables instead of just using them directly from the `$tasks` array we populated earlier, use a `foreach`:

```
foreach ($tasks as $key => $task) {
    ${'line'.($key + 1)} = $tasks[$key];
}
```

Really, the most conventional thing to do here would just be to keep the tasks in the `$tasks` array created inside the `while` loop instead of populating a potentially unknown number of variables, adding them to the local or global symbol table unnecessarily. If the tasks are related (they arguably are, simply since they are all *tasks*), then it is wise to keep them bound together in an array.

```
// Use $tasks as an array, don't populate variables:
foreach ($tasks as $key => $task) {
  echo "Task $key from array: $task<br/>\n"; 
}
```

As noted in comments, watch out for mixing up `mysql_*()` with the `mysqli_*()` APIs. Your call to `mysql_error()` should be instead a call to `mysqli_error($usermysqli)`

Comment: This is a really good answer and has helped me out a lot!  I'm going to just keep the $tasks array created inside the while loop as you recommended but the methods you gave me above are also extremely helpful for my own knowledge.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Store the tasks as an array. Try this code - is untested and warranty free but quite straightforward.

```
$tasks = [];  // array to store tasks

while($tasks_displayed = $tasks_result->fetch_array()) {  // could use fetch_row instead?

    $tasks[] = $tasks_displayed[0];

}

var_dump($tasks);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer to your question, but instead another approach to the problem you outlined

```
// Retrieve tasks from the tasks table 
$tasks_sql = "SELECT DISTINCT taskname FROM tasks";
$tasks_result = mysqli_query($usermysqli, $tasks_sql);
if (! $tasks_result){
      die('Could not retrieve data: ' . mysql.error());
    }

// Array for assigning tasknames to global variables


$tasks_displayed = $tasks_result->fetch_array();

foreach( $tasks_displayed as $key => $value )
{
    echo "Task ".($key + 1)." from array: " . $value . "<br>";
}
```